# Magento: Display price twice on product pages

Tags: magento

This is the code that generates the price on product pages:

```
<?php  echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

in ***app/design/frontend/default/CUSTOM_TEMPLATE/template/catalog/product/view.phtml***

I have a simple product with a few custom options. When the customer selects one of the option, the price increases. All works fine until here.

**My question is how can i display the price twice on the same page (*need this for deign purposes*)?**

I tried to copy and paste the above code in two locations on the same page, but the problem is that the second price will not update when the product options are selected. Only one price updates, the second won't. Any ideas on how can i make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is most likely a JavaScript on the page that either calculates the new price, or fetches it with AJAX. So the price outputted with:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

Will get overwritten by the new one.  Solving this requires that you find the Javascript and locate where it does this. You should also check what HTML element surrounds the getPriceHtml-call. I guess the template might have something like this:

```
<p class="totalProductPrice"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?></p>
```

If you surround the output of your second price output with an element with identifiable classname or ID, you should be able to modify the Javascript to output the newly calculated price to that element as well as the original one.

**EDIT:**

After checking my own codebase, I think that the file you are looking for is located at `/js/varien/Product.js`. Inside the function `reloadPrice: function()`, check line 481 for this:

```
    if($('product-price-'+this.config.productId)){
        $('product-price-'+this.config.productId).innerHTML = price;
    }
```

And modify the script to also update your second price element.

Comment: @OlivierVandeVelde i do not remeber as i have not work with this in more than 4 years

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was:

Copy the **price_clone.phtml** to **price_clone2.phtml** and change:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '_clone2') ?>
```

Add the block in the **catalog.xml**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices2" as="prices2" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone2.phtml"/>
```

And in the **product.js** change the **initPrices function**

```
initPrices: function() {
    this.containers[0] = 'product-price-' + this.productId;
    this.containers[1] = 'bundle-price-' + this.productId;
    this.containers[2] = 'price-including-tax-' + this.productId;
    this.containers[3] = 'price-excluding-tax-' + this.productId;
    this.containers[4] = 'old-price-' + this.productId;
    this.containers[5] = 'product-price-' + this.productId+'_clone2';
},
```