# Use multiple price in magento but it doesn't update when change the custom option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

So basically, I need to display two different price for a single product,
 I manage to display the both of prices itself.
But when I change the custom option only one price is changing, the second price does not response.

If you see the image below you will find two prices and the smaller one ain't changing when the custom options have been change.

I saw this post [Magento: Display price twice on product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424946/magento-display-price-twice-on-product-pages)
it mention about change/add new method under **Product.js** but i am still looking for some idea to help.

Comment: Why don't you use special price and regular price?

Comment: Because my customer has special requirement of this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check price code which was added if it is added like this :

`<?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice();?>`

then same code you need to write for second price.

Comment: This only display the price. But what i need is to ensure both prices will be updated when the custom option changed. Thanks anyway.